# How to update MongoDB by Object ID with C++ driver?

Tags: c++, mongodb

I think I have exhausted all available documentation on this.  Using the C++ BSON drivers for Mongo, I would like to find a record from Mongo, then perform an update on that record based on the found records object id.  The main area I'm struggling with is the update query.  An example of what I've tried that doesn't work:

```
db.update("mydb.mycollection",
          QUERY("_id" << ObjectID("521e68e5b9efcf5a9dff7052")),
          BSON("$set" << BSON("somefield" << "11111")));
```

I cannot find a shred of documentation on how to use the C++ driver to query from or update based on the _id field, which in my example is my only unique field.  Any example code would be much appreciated, especially one that runs a find query, picks off the objectID, and then updates a field on that particular document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the very helpful answer from WiredPrarie to get to the bottom of this....  Below is an example of the code used to 1) pluck the ObjectID ("_id") field from an existing query (in this case the result variable is called "tx", and pass it to an update query along with the update parameters for that query.

```
// Update order based on objectid
db.update("dakota.transaction",
          QUERY("_id" << tx.getField("_id")),
          BSON("$set" << BSON("somefield" << "11111")));
```

It should be noted that the answer posted by WiredPrarie is also correct in using OID to cast a string manually - just lacks the last set of params needed by mongo to update the data to something new

Comment: Done, sorry bad form.

Comment: I'm not sure what you did?

Answer (score 3):

I don't have the driver compiled, however, I thought it was casting to an `OID`?

```
db.update("mydb.mycollection", QUERY("_id" << OID("521e68e5b9efcf5a9dff7052")))
```

In any case, there are a number of test cases located [here](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/tree/master/src/mongo/dbtests) that may/not prove useful that I've used in the past to "learn" how to do some things in the very poorly documented driver.

Answer (score 1):

**Try This Code:**

```
db.update("tutorial.persons",
       BSON("name" << "Joe" << "age" << 33),
       BSON("$inc" << BSON( "visits" << 1)));
```